# Input parameters to web method becoming null

Tags: c#, web-services

I created a asmx service for existing client. The service works fine from SOAP UI but when called from external client the input parameters are becoming null. I tried calling the service from Console application using httpWebRequest (without adding service reference), the issue persists. This seems to be happening only when calling the service over https.
Oddly, the soapheader parameters are coming properly.
The client sends SoapAction as empty and cannot be modified hence used

```
[SoapDocumentMethodAttribute(Action = "")]

[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
public class Validate : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    private WSSEDraftSecurityHeader _security;

    public WSSEDraftSecurityHeader Security
    {
        get { return _security; }
        set { _security = value; }

    }

    [WebMethod]
    [SoapDocumentMethodAttribute(Action = "")]
    [SoapHeader("Security", Direction = SoapHeaderDirection.InOut)]
    public ValidateResponse.validateResult validate(DateTime dt, string ac, string tc, string ot, string o, int sn, string bpb)
    {
    }
}
```

The Soap Request is:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"> <s:Header> <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"> <o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-9b091270-fad3-4cf7-bef5-58b9a57ed37e-9"> <o:Username>XXXXX</o:Username> <o:Password>iiiiii</o:Password> </o:UsernameToken> </o:Security> </s:Header> <s:Body> <validate xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"> <ac>SN</ac> <bpb>TTFD</bpb> <o>PXPXS1</o> <ot>port</ot> <sn>0</sn> <tc>T2</tc> <dt>2019-04-17T18:50:36.3259364+08:00</dt> </validate> </s:Body> </s:Envelope>
```

The web method is being called and passing the security header validation. But all string parameters coming as null and one date time parameter coming with default date of 01/01/0001

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the issue is with the order of the parameters in Soap request, as they are listed in different order than in your method declaration. I would compare SOAP requests generated by SoapUI and Console app and then find the differences.